# Flex ColdFusion connection issue with AIR app

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, air, flex4, coldfusion-9

I have a smoothly running web Flex app which interacts with a database via ColdFusion.
However, when I try and adapt it for AIR I get this error:

```
Send failed
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: : url: 'http://iki_Lyric_Air.swf/flex2gateway/'
```

I am running it locally and the swf should be `iki_Lyric_Air.swf`. I tried changing/shortening the name of the project but the first letter was still omitted.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You stated that the filename is being truncated but in your example they are the same.  Can you correct that please?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the URL is of the type http://[server IP]/flex2gateway/. Please check the URL that your services or Remote Calls are pointing to.